# Recording and uploading video in mobile browser using device's camera

Tags: video-recording, mobile-browser

An application is being developed in asp.net mvc3 along with jQuery. Recording and uploading video has been done using Flash object and jquery plugin for uploading altogether in desktop browsers.

The challenging thing is it has to be the same in mobile browser too. Since the Flash is not supported in mobile devices, needs a solution for recording a video from mobile browser and uploading it.

Can anyone give references or solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use default html5 input file tag using accept attribute as "video/*". It will give you a chance to record or select video from its camera on mobile. Hope it helps.

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" />
```